# Copy Data from Cell A to B and convert to Number

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is copying the data fine, however the copy when then number is copied over is copied as text. Is there any way to copy it over as a number?

```
    Worksheets(1).Range(destCol1 & LR & destCol2 & LR).cells(3).value = Split(srcRange(5).value)
```

I've tried recording a macro where I'd highlight the data and click the option "Convert text to number" but it's not recording the VBA for that part.

**EDIT 1:**

```
With Worksheets(1).Range(destCol1 & LR & destCol2 & LR)
    .cells(1).value = srcRange(2).text
    .cells(2).value = srcRange(1).value
    .cells(3).value = CDbl(Split(srcRange(5).value)(1))
    .cells(4).value = srcRange(6).value 
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of digging, I found another answer on these forums [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771458/vba-convert-text-to-number)

I would ideally like to have it all done it one line to reduce processing power as these pages can get quite large; unfortunately this was the best solution I could get.

**EDIT:**

Using the below code that I modified a bit, but it does work

```
Private Function TextToNumber(rng As Range)

    LR = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For R = LR To 3 Step -1
        With rng.cells(R, 1)
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .value = .value
        End With
    Next R

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub jdskfhs()
    Worksheets(1).Range(destCol1 & LR & destCol2 & LR).Cells(3).Value = CDbl(Split(srcRange(5).Value))
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is what you need:

```
Sub jdskfhs2()
    Worksheets(1).Range(destCol1 & LR & destCol2 & LR).Cells(3).Value = CDbl(Split(srcRange(5).Value)(1))
End Sub
```

This new code converts the **second** element of the `Split()`-generated array to a number.

Comment: @Maldred  any spaces in the data ?

Comment: Yes, that's what the Split() is doing... I've just tried splitting it first, and storing the split string into a temp variable and I'm still getting the same error, but it's a type mismatch error on the Split() function

Comment: Post an example of the data you are trying to put into the cell.

Comment: `12000541         DUP-` would be one example, there are approximately 12 spaces in there

Comment: @Maldred  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Still getting the same compile error... I do have this in a With statement, would that make any difference?