# While exporting table in access to sheet in excel, I need to set Date and Number value in Excel row

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have written a small code to export a query from Access to a sheet in Excel.

In the Excel sheet i have one problem; there is one row (underneath a header) that need to be converted into a

- number value

Basically my VBA code should do what i now have to do by hand.

- Number value: Select the cells containing the numbers.
  Press  (popup) and select "convert to number"

I already have this

```
wks.range("Z2:Z" & rs.RecordCount + 1).numberformat = "General"
```

but it doesn't work

For reference below is my full code

```
SUB UnknownProcName

  Dim appXL As Object
  Dim wb As Object
  Dim wks As Object
  Dim xlf As String
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

  'Full path to Excel file'


  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("openPOLIST")
  Set wks = wb.Sheets("INP.OpenPOlist")

  wks.range("A1").select
  For Each fld In rs.Fields
      appXL.ActiveCell = fld.Name
      appXL.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).select
  Next
  wks.range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
  wks.range("A1" & rs.RecordCount + 1).Columns.AutoFit

  wks.range("Z2:Z" & rs.RecordCount + 1).numberformat = "General"

  rs.Close
  wb.Save
  wb.Close
  appXL.Quit
  Set wb = Nothing
  Set rs = Nothing

  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  MsgBox ("Well... it does give a warning...")
End Sub
```

After i run the export the number it looks like this After export and has indeed the text value:

[image]

When I press this button and choose convert to number it has the desired value

[image]

and looks like this after manual change

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtk7J.png]

Comment: I believe you'll find the answer to converting text to numbers in this Stack Overflow discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771458/vba-convert-text-to-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Cindy for helping me out and finding the answer. The code in the link you provided didnt work for me straight away but after playing around with it a bit i came up with the following

`wks.range("Z2:Z" & rs.RecordCount + 1).NumberFormat = "0"
 wks.range("Z2:Z" & rs.RecordCount + 1).Value = wks.range("Z2:Z" & rs.RecordCount + 1).Value`

This finally solved my problem. Thank you so much for the help !