# Attempting to use PowerShell to emulate the Convert to Number function in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell

I receive a file everyday that I need to insert data into then process and format it to get a useful report. I am very new to PowerShell, but I am trying to automate this to save some time, and learn as I go.

The issue I am running into now is Column A has numeric values stored as text. While manually formatting it, I would normally click the popup next to the cell, which then gives an option of "Convert to Number". How do I emulate this using PowerShell? I have attempted a few different methods that have allowed me to format the text number, but none of them have managed to convert it from text to number. Another way of manually doing it is by going to Data -> Text to Columns, but even manually this doesn't seem like the appropriate way of doing this.

I need this as a number and not text because later in the process it will be used in a vlookup.
Also this column is in the initial report I receive, which is a .xlsx file, not part of the data I am pulling from our database.

```
$date = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyy.MM.dd.")

$dbserver = "server"
$dbdatabase = "database"
$dbuser = "user"
$dbpass = "password"
$conn = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection
$conn.connectionstring = "server=$dbserver;database=$dbdatabase;user id=$dbuser;password=$dbpass;"

$query = @"
SELECT DISTINCT
    ORS.Reference2 AS 'CDL OrderID',
    ORS.PKID AS 'Sonic Tracking',
    D.DisplayCode AS 'HUB',
    ZRZ.RouteID AS 'Default Route',
    ORS.ROUTEID AS 'Assigned Route',
    CAST(ORS.CREATEDWHEN AS DATE) AS 'Order Created Date',
    p2.createdwhen  AS 'RECEIVE Scan Date',
    CASE WHEN p2.createdby like 'driver 9[0-9][0-9][0-9]' then 'Y'
         ELSE ''    
         END AS 'Scanned?',
    ORS.POSTDATE AS 'Post Date',
    ors.pod AS 'POD',
    ORS.COMPLETEDTIME AS 'CompletedTime',
    (STUFF((SELECT ', ', EC.ExceptionDesc, ' ( Added: ',  OSC.createdWhen, ' By: ',OSC.createdBy, ') ' 
    FROM tblOrderRouteStops_StatusCodes OSC 
    LEFT JOIN tblexceptioncodes ec on osc.statuscode = ec.exceptionid
    WHERE OSC.ORSID = ORS.PKID 
    ORDER BY osc.createdwhen
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ' ') )
    AS  'Status Code'     

FROM tblOrderRouteStops ORS
    LEFT JOIN tblParcel P ON ORS.PKID = P.ORDERID and p.reference like '128%AP1'
    Left Join tblParcel p2 on p.reference = p2.reference and p2.createdby like 'driver 9[0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
    LEFT JOIN tblZones Z ON ORS.Zip = Z.Zip
    LEFT JOIN tblDepots D ON Z.DepotID = D.DepotID
    LEFT JOIN tblZonesRouteZones ZRZ ON Z.ZoneID = ZRZ.ZoneID AND ZRZ.ROUTELOOKUPID = 1
    LEFT JOIN tblOrderRouteStops_StatusCodes OSC ON ORS.PKID = OSC.ORSID
    LEFT JOIN tblExceptionCodes EC ON OSC.statusCode = EC.ExceptionID

WHERE 1=1
      
    AND ORS.CUSTID = 3919
    AND ORS.CREATEDWHEN > '2021-06-10'
    AND ORS.REFERENCE2 <> ''
      
ORDER BY ORS.pkid DESC

"@

$sqlcmd = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand
$sqlcmd.CommandText = $query
$sqlcmd.Connection = $conn
$sqladpt = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter
$sqladpt.selectcommand = $sqlcmd
$data = new-object system.data.dataset
$sqladpt.fill($data)
$dataset = $data.Tables[0] 


#$wb = 'C:\Users\jthompson\Desktop\CDL Daily\' + $date + 'ReviewOrders.xlsx'
$wb = 'C:\Users\jthompson\Desktop\CDL Daily\test.xlsx'
$excel = new-object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $excel.workbooks.open($wb)
$ws1 = $wb.worksheets.item(1)
$ws2 = $wb.worksheets.add()

$dataset | convertto-csv -notype -delimiter `t | clip
[void]$ws2.cells.item(1).pastespecial()

$ws2.usedrange.entirecolumn.autofit()
$ws1.UsedRange.horizontalalignment = -4131
$ws2.UsedRange.horizontalalignment = -4131
$ws2.columns.item(6).numberformat = "MM/dd/yyy"
$ws2.columns.item(7).numberformat = "MM/dd/yyy"
$ws2.columns.item(9).numberformat = "MM/dd/yyy"
$ws2.columns.item(1).numberformat = "0.000001"

//this will format it with the correct decimals, but does not change it from text to number  
$ws1.columns.item(1).numberformat = 0.000001


$wb.Save()
$wb.close()
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
Remove-Variable excel
```

---

Edit

[Message stating number in cell is formatted as text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59ZLI.png)

[Format cell dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyVuX.png)

To clarify, after I use numberFormat, in the "Format Cells" dialogue box it states they are formatted as decimals with 6 places. However they still have the green triangle, and the popup with the message " The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe".
Even when I manually format it the only way I have found to change it from text to numeric is by clicking "Convert to Number" or "Text to Column". Changing the format in "Format Cells" seems to have no effect on this.

No it is not a table and it is not linked to a data import. I receive this report from a customer, so it has no connections or dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE (February 7, 2022), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163828/using-powershell-to-convert-text-to-number-in-excel):

Depending on your version of Excel, you may need to use `.Value2` or `.Value(10)` instead of `.Value`:

```
$ws1.Columns.Item(1).Value2 = $ws1.Columns.Item(1).Value2
```

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36771459/9245853), you can use:

```
$ws1.Columns.Item(1).Value = $ws1.Columns.Item(1).Value
```

Note that a cell's format and its underlying value are two separate things. Changing the `NumberFormat` (manually or programmatically) doesn't change the underlying value.

Comment: Fantastic! That did it. If you could elaborate on how that worked I would appreciate it. It appears to me to have took the format of the column, which was set to decimal, and reapplied it to the column, thus overriding the text effect. Similar to copying a range with functions, and pasting it onto itself with values only?

Comment: It doesn't work with the format, but the value (they're two separate things), and it's similar to pasting values, yes.

Comment: @mklement0 - `.Value` and `.Value2` are slightly different in that the latter does not use the Currency and Date data types. So I guess, it depends on what is desired and what data is actually in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormat` is the correct property - try out:

```sh
$excel = new-object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $excel.workbooks.open('c:\temp\test.xlsx')
$ws1 = $wb.worksheets.item(1)
$ws1.Columns.Item(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.000000"

$wb.Save()
$wb.close()
$excel.Quit()
```

I tested this with a very simple .xlsx doc:

```
A B
- -
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

before changing the format, I verified the numbers got saved in General format using `$ws1.Columns.Item(1).NumberFormat`. It returns General before the change, and returned Number format after saving and re-opening the file.

Comment: No luck, similar output as before.

Comment: @Jeff I added more detail to my answer, maybe you'll be able to see how your situation is different. Is your data in an Excel Table? Is it linked to a Data Import (overrides column formatting)?

Comment: No it is not a table and it is not linked to a data import. I receive this report from a customer, so it has no connections or dependencies.

Comment: `NumberFormat` doesn't change the underlying value, and will not change text-that-looks-like-a-number to an actual number.

Comment: @Jeff - can you try (in the spirit of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36771459/9245853)), `$ws1.Columns.Item(1).Value = $ws1.Columns.Item(1).Value`?

Comment: @Jeff BigBen is right, I missed the important part. The reason it works seems to be that excel's `$cell.value()` method automatically converts cell values to `double` when reading from the document even if they were stored as text. You can achieve a similar result in excel using `VALUE()`. For example: `=VLOOKUP(VALUE(A1),B1:C1,2,FALSE)`. You probably want to also set the `NumberFormat` property to display the right number of decimals.