# Using Powershell to convert text to number in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an excel file that has three columns that are set to Number. However, when I open the file I have the this :

[image: convert to number]

I found a helpful link here: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941811/attempting-to-use-powershell-to-emulate-the-convert-to-number-function-in-excel)

I have tried this method but I am getting the following error. Is there something I am doing wrong:

```
$wb = 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\Working Folder\239\239_uploadFile.xlsx'
$excel = new-object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $excel.workbooks.open($wb)
$ws1 = $wb.worksheets.item(3)

$ws1.columns.item(1).numberformat = 0
$ws1.Columns.item(14).Value = $ws1.Columns.item(14).Value



$wb.Save()
$wb.close()
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
Remove-Variable excel`
```

[[image: Powershell error]

Comment: I think they are under the misconception that `.Item(1)` indicates the first cell in the column. Either that or it is a typo and they just missed the `4`.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Yes, please ignore.. I was thinking `Columns(1)`, not `Columns.Item(1)`

Comment: @Theo Those are the same thing in this case. If you want to reference cells you need to do `$ws1.Columns.item(14).cells.item(1).numberformat = 0` or something like that, to reference cell N1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In recent versions of Excel (as of *at least* Excel 2019), the **`.Value` property is now a *parameterized* property and therefore requires an *argument* in order to be used**.

  - A **simple *workaround*** is to **use the `.Value2` property instead** - shown below.
  - However, **[`.Value2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2?view=excel-pia)** differs from [`.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value?view=excel-pia) in that "it **doesn’t use the *Currency* and *Date* data types**" - if those types are required, **use `.Value(10)`** (sic) instead (`10` is the value of the `xlRangeValueDefault` constant).
- While using the `.Item()` method explicitly *used to be* required in earlier PowerShell (Core) versions, this no longer the case as of (at least) PowerShell (Core) 7.2.1.

Therefore, try the following:

```
& {
  $wb = 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\Working Folder\239\239_uploadFile.xlsx'
  $excel = new-object -ComObject excel.application

  $wb = $excel.workbooks.open($wb)
  $ws1 = $wb.worksheets(3)

  $ws1.columns(1).numberformat = 0
  # Note the use of .Value2, not .Value
  $ws1.Columns(14).Value2 = $ws1.Columns(14).Value2

  $wb.Save()
  $wb.close()
  $excel.Quit()
}
```

Note the use of `& { ... }`, i.e. the execution of the Excel-related code in a *child scope*. This makes the calls to and `Remove-Variable excel` unnecessary - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55423449/45375) for more information.