# PowerShell test a specific excel cell if it contains the text "entry number"

Tags: excel, powershell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am testing an Excel file to see if cell C2 contains the text "entry number". If it does take one action else take a different action.

```
# $Invoice3 = $worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value
$test2 = "C:\Test\samplefile.xlsx"

$be = $test1[2].col2  

#$characterCount = $InvoiceC3.Length
# Check if cell C2 contains the text "Entry Number"
 if ($be -eq "Entry Number") {
    Write-Host "It does contain Entry Number"}
    else {
    Write-Host "It does not contain Entry Number"
    }
```

I have tried checking the length of the cell and the value, but no luck. I am open to any approaches that work best. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, don't have excel installed to test.

```
$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application # Register Excel Object
$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(".\Book.xlsx") # Load a Workbook
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item("Sheet1") # Get a specific sheet
$cell = "B2" # Placeholder for what cell we want
$cellValue = $ExcelWorkSheet.cells.Item($cell).text # Get contents of that cell
if ($cellValue -eq "Entry Number") {
    Write-Host "It does contain Entry Number"}
else {
    Write-Host "Not there"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

> `$worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value`

with

```bash
$worksheet.Range("C2").Value(10) # or .Text, to get a string value
```

Note:

- In order to specify so-called A1-format addresses such as `C2` (which refers to the third column (`C`) and the second (`2`) row), the parameterized [`.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.range#microsoft-office-interop-excel-worksheet-range(system-object-system-object)) property must be used.

  - By contrast, if you use the [`.Cells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.cells) property with the same syntax, its parameterized [`.Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.item#microsoft-office-interop-excel-range-item(system-object-system-object)) property is used, which accepts only (1-based) row and column *numbers*, so the equivalent expression would be `.Cells(2, 3)` (note that, unlike in A1 format, it is the *row* number that comes first).
- In both cases, the address / row and column numbers are relative to the input object (i.e. a given worksheet or range).
- Note the use of `(...)` rather than `[...]`:

  - Unfortunately, the docs show the latter, because they default to showing *C#* syntax; switching to VB via the dropdown list at the top of the main pane shows the use of `(...)`.
- `.Value(10)` is required to return the cell value(s) with the most *type fidelity*, using the parameterized [`.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value#microsoft-office-interop-excel-range-value(system-object)) property

  - If you do not care about currency and date values to be returned as such, you can use [`.Value2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2#microsoft-office-interop-excel-range-value2) (no parentheses).
  - If you want a *string* representation - irrespective of the actual data type - use [`.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.text#microsoft-office-interop-excel-range-text).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71165173/45375) for more information.

---

A complete example:

```bash
# Note: Be sure to specify a *full path*, because COM's working directory
#       usually differs from PowerShell's
#       To use a relative path, pass it to the Convert-Path cmdlet, e.g.:
#          Convert-Path .\samplefile.xlsx
$xlFile = 'C:\Test\samplefile.xlsx'

# Note: & { ... } executes the code in a *child scope*, which 
#       ensures that all COM object references are properly released
#       after calling $xl.Quit(), thereby causing the Excel process to exit.
& {

  # Create the Excel object (this starts a hidden excel.exe process)
  $xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

  # Get the first worksheet.
  $worksheet = $xl.Workbooks.Open($xlFile).Worksheets(1)

  # Test the value of cell C2 for containing the text 'Entry Number'
  if ($worksheet.Range('C2').Text -eq 'Entry Number') {
    'It does contain Entry Number'
  else {
    'It does not contain Entry Number'
  }

  # Tell the Excel process to quit.
  $xl.Quit()

}
```